# How to deploy a website to vercel with external backend server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel, react-fullstack

hey i have a project with a client folder and a server folder.
in the client folder im using next.js.
in the server folder im using node.js.

now i know i can build my backend with next.js api,
but i want my backend to be separted from my client.

now i want to deploy my project to vercel it is possible to deploy my project,
with my server and not only the client side?
and if soo in my client i need to change the axio baseUrl to what?

i did deploy my client folder to varcel and its working fine, but i want my external server to
run aswell.

Comment: Vercel doesn't provide free hosting solutions for servers. You will have to use some other cloud provider like Heroku (beginner friendly), AWS (advanced), Azure (advanced), GCP (advanced), etc. On a side note, why do you want your server separate from the client? NextJS APIs get deployed on independent lambdas and they scale very well.

Comment: @vighnesh153 ohh ok ty for the response, yea i think i transfer my backend code to nextjs.